# Find variable declaration for variable identifier (Eclipse JDT ASTNode)

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm analyzing ASTNodes (org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom) and I'm trying to find the VariableDeclaration for a variable node (SimpleName) that I have. Example:

```
String foo = "bar"; // <-- need to get node for 'foo' (VariableDeclaration)
....
....
return foo; // <-- have node for 'foo' (SimpleName)
```

I also need a solution that can find the declaration if it's a class field.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the specifics of what you are doing, here's how I would do something like this in general in simple terms:

I would walk the AST to every VarDecl, and send the left child node to an "AST node -> source location" function to see if the "source location" text matched foo.